# How to use MediaSource API for playing audios?

Tags: javascript, audio

I have a collection of audio segments stored on the server. How can i stream those segments using MediaSource API so that the client can play them as they are fetched?

Comment: have you tried incrementing the version of the database, deleting the object store, and creating a new object store?

Comment: I did but for new data to be entered into the db , the page had to be refreshed.

Comment: no, i mean, every single time the page is loaded, your script has to check if the database exists, if not then create version 1, if exists then get current version, then delete store, then open new version = current version + 1 and recreate store